# Declared as an inner class but error "must be declared abstract or implement" persists

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask `GoogleBookAsyncTask` that I want to run in a
Fragment. I am following this other SO
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12575319/3034693). It requires my
Fragment class `BookListingActivityFragment` to implement an interface
`AsyncResponse` and declare its abstract method `onProcessFinish()`.

The `onProcessFinish()` in my Fragment is declare as an anonymous
class life following.

```
public GoogleBookAsyncTask mGoogleBookAsyncTask = new GoogleBookAsyncTask(new AsyncResponse() {
    @Override
    public void processFinish(ArrayList<Book> bookArrayList) {
        mBookArrayAdapter.clear();
        mBookArrayAdapter = new BookAdapter(getContext(), bookArrayList);
        mBookArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

I get an error `must either be declared abstract or implement abstract
method`. This error goes away if I declare `processFinish()` as a
regular non-inner class. How can I resolve this error? I need to
execute `mGoogleBookAsyncTask.execute()` to get data from my AsyncTask
class.

The full source code my app can be found [here](https://github.com/sudhirkhanger/BookListingApp).

Comment: "This error goes away if I declare onProcessFinish() as a regular non-inner class" -- `onProcessFinish()` is a method. It is not a class. "The full source code my app can be found here." -- there is no `AsyncTask` in that repository. Nor is there a `GoogleBookAsyncTask` or an `AsyncResponse`. Please provide a [mcve], including the source code for `GoogleBookAsyncTask` and `AsyncResponse`.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare I am sorry about that. I have fixed the project link and the onProcessFinish() typo. Please take a look.

Comment: "I get an error must either be declared abstract or implement abstract
method" -- what abstract method is it saying that you should implement? Or, if your IDE supports a quick-fix to add the method, what method does it add? BTW, this code should crash (`mBookArrayAdapter` will be `null`), and there is no point in calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on a adapter that is not attached to an `AdapterView`.

Comment: `BookListingActivityFragment` implements interface `AsyncResponse` which has one method `processFinish(ArrayList<>)`. As a result I have to implement `processFinish(ArrayList<>)` in the BookListingActivityFragment class. I have implemented `processFinish` as an annonymous class of an instance of GoogleBookAsyncTask. See the error http://imgur.com/a/yMjMA. If I use implement `AsyncResponse` I have to declare processFinish but if I don't implement `AsyncResponse` interface I can still run everything and it works. if `mBookArrayAdapter` is null I set a TextView which shows `no data found` text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I implement AsyncResponse, I have to declare `processFinish`

Yes, that is **exactly** what that error tells you.

> but if I don't implement `AsyncResponse` interface I can still run everything and it works.

Then why care about the error at all?

---

If you want to fix the problem, then **do** implement the interface on the class, and instead do this.

```
public class BookListingActivityFragment extends Fragment 
        implements AsyncResponse {

    private GoogleBookAsyncTask mGoogleBookAsyncTask;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // .......

            // Pass "delegate" interface as 'this'
            mGoogleBookAsyncTask = new GoogleBookAsyncTask(this);
            mmGoogleBookAsyncTask.execute();
        }

    // This is the interface implementation that is called from the AsyncTask
    @Override
    public void processFinish(ArrayList<Book> bookArrayList) {
        mBookArrayAdapter.clear();
        mBookArrayAdapter = new BookAdapter(getContext(), bookArrayList);
        mBookArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. What does `this` reference to in `new GoogleBookAsyncTask(this);`?

Comment: Can you please explain why it wasn't working the way it was explained in the SO post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a/12575319#12575319

Comment: The "first" solution there looks correct. I've edited  the second solution so it compiles. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is what I think it is, it should say this almost exactly: `anonymous class <your class> is not abstract, and does not implement method <some method> from <some interface>`. If this is what you are seeing, then that means you are not implementing another abstract method in that interface.